# How to set up Unit Testing using FETCH

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I have been trying to set up a unit testing on VSC - JS /React for the following code below.

```
getNotificationgetNotificationCount = () =>{
fetch(`${this.state.services.NotificationReporting.URL}/NOTIFICATIONS?$count=true&$filter=contains(Notified,'${this.state.user.Email}') and Status eq 'Unread'`, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': this.state.services.NotificationReporting.subscription_key,
    "DDHFirm": this.state.user.DDHFirm
  },
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
})
.then(res => {return(validationManager.ResolveHTTPResponse(res, 'Request Successful', 'Request Failed', res.ok ? true : false))})
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      unreadNotifications: response.body ? response.body['@odata.count'] : 0,
    })
  })
```

}

Expecting the function/method gets call at the moment. Actual results will be handle later

Comment: You don't. I/O tests are integration tests, not unit tests. As long as your logic is cleanly separated from I/O, you don't need to unit test the latter at all.

Comment: @thepirat000 how can I tell the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a spy in the function to check if it has been called:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'getNotificationgetNotificationCount');
const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
// Next line will call the function, replace it with
// any code that will trigger the call
wrapper.instance().getNotificationgetNotificationCount();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This will just check if the function has been called, regardless of the results.

Comment: Thanks .I will try to run it right now, under a test.js file. Is there anything missing on it ?

Comment: You need to setup your test by enclosing this code in a describe / it statements

Comment: I am definitely stating a Unit test course online , just started doing it : `                                                                                          describe('App', () => {
it('should call', () => {
const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'getNotificationgetNotificationCount')
const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />)
// Next line will call the function, replace it with
// any code that will trigger the call
wrapper.instance().getNotificationgetNotificationCount();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}) 
}) `

Comment: And do I have to add   instance.forceUpdate();  before wrapper.instance()